# phonegap battery status plugin not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Ciao I am testing a battery-status plugin, but does not work.
I'm using  PhoneGap Desktop and i installed the plugin with command line :

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-battery-status
```

I'm sure that the plugin is installed on plugins directory.

This is my HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>test batteria</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>test batteria</h1>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       app.initialize();
    </script>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("batterystatus", onBatteryStatus, true);

        function onBatteryStatus(status) 
        {
            alert("Level: " + status.level + " isPlugged: " + status.isPlugged);
        }


    </script>
</body>
```

Where am I wrong?
grazie ciao

Answer (score 3):

Any plugin you should access after **deviceready** event is fired. So change the script as follows

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",function(){
   window.addEventListener("batterystatus", onBatteryStatus, true);
},false);

function onBatteryStatus(status) 
    {
        alert("Level: " + status.level + " isPlugged: " + status.isPlugged);
    }
```

It should work... Hope it helps to you.

Comment: thank you, it works!
I tried to remove the plugin and the build platform . The plugin works too ... I think it's weird. 
Why it works equally?

Comment: It happens because some times plugin might haven't installed properly